# How do you validate a OneToMany entity form collection?

Tags: forms, symfony, validation, symfony-2.1

I have a products table that has a one-to-many relationship with a product to departments table where a product can be associated with one or more departments.

I am having a problem when I am adding a new product to validate my department.

If I do not select a department the form still validates and submits.

Here is where I build the form.

```
class NewProductType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('departments', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new ProductDepartmentType(),
            'required' => true,
        ));
...
```

The collection is setup through the ProductDepartmentType class:

```
class ProductDepartmentType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('department', 'entity', array(
            'property' => 'indentedName',
            'class' => 'WebIllumination\SiteBundle\Entity\Department',
            'query_builder' => function(EntityRepository $er) {
                return $er->createQueryBuilder('d')
                    ->addSelect('dd')
                    ->leftJoin('d.descriptions', 'dd')
                    ->orderBy('d.displayOrder', 'ASC');
            },
            'required' => true,
            'empty_value' => '- Select a Department -',
        ), array());
        $builder->add('displayOrder', 'hidden');
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        $collectionConstraint = new Collection(array(
            'department' => array(
                new NotBlank(array('message' => 'Select a department.')),
            ),
        ));

        return array(
            'validation_constraint' => $collectionConstraint,
        );
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'site_product_department';
    }
}
```

I then tried adding the following into the ProductDepartmentType:

```
class ProductDepartmentType extends AbstractType
{
...
    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => 'WebIllumination\SiteBundle\Entity\ProductToDepartment'
        ));
    }
...
```

This had no affect and the form can still be submitted without being validated.

Can anyone help me work out how I can validate this field?

Answer (score 1):

When you have nested forms the errors are not passed to the parent form by default. In your child form you need to set `error_bubbling => true` on the fields you wish to validate, this will pass the error to the parent form. http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#error-bubbling

Comment: I thought that originally, but it made no difference.